# Cumulative deposits with fixed rate decay

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to model the accumulation of biomass from dead wood deposited anually. The wood decays at a rate of 4.6% each year.

My data is formatted:

Cols: Treatment, Year, New.deposit
Treatment (A, B, C...)
Year (0:105)
New.deposit (numeric)

For the past few days, I've tried a combination of functions looking roughly as follows, but ended up with wrong combinations - maybe I'm making things too difficult:

```
#OBS! These code attempts are incorrect.
df <- df %>% group_by(Treatment) %>% mutate(Accumulated.deposits = cumsum(lag(New.deposit, n=1, default=0))*(1-0.046))

df <- df %>% group_by(Treatment) %>% mutate(Accumulated.deposits = cumsum((lag(Accumulated.deposits, n=1, default=0)*(1-0.046))) + new.deposit

My goal is to have one variable, Accumulated.biomass.yearY = deposit.year0 *  (1-0.046)^(Y) + deposit.year1 * (1-0.046)^(Y-1) + deposit.year2 * (1-0.046)^(Y-2)..... deposit.yearY * (1-0.046)^(Y-Y).
```

I would love an matrix showing amount of remaining biomass from each years deposit at year X.

Comment: Are deposits once-a-year process and decay a continuous-throughout-the-year process? Or are deposits also continuous?

Comment: @CPak , deposits are once-a-year. To make this model simple, so is the decay. :-)

Comment: Ok, I see both are once-a-year now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(treatment = rep(c('A','B'), each=5), years = rep(1:5, times=2), new_deposit=runif(10))

   treatment years new_deposit
1          A     1  0.26550866
2          A     2  0.37212390
3          A     3  0.57285336
4          A     4  0.90820779
5          A     5  0.20168193
6          B     1  0.89838968
7          B     2  0.94467527
8          B     3  0.66079779
9          B     4  0.62911404
10         B     5  0.06178627
```

Custom function

```
custom <- function(z, decay) { ans <- accumulate(z, function(x, y) { (x + y) * (1-decay) }, .init=0); tail(ans, -1) }
```

The function will take a vector `z` and decay-rate `decay` and using `purrr::accumulate` will recursively apply the formula `(x+y)*(1-decay)` where `x` is the `i`th element in the vector and `y` is the `i+1`th element in the vector. I pad the vector `.init=0` with a starting value of 0 and return the answer without padding `tail(ans, -1)`.

Usage

```
df %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  mutate(accumulated = custom(new_deposit, 0.046))

    treatment years new_deposit accumulated
   <fct>     <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A             1      0.266        0.253
 2 A             2      0.372        0.597
 3 A             3      0.573        1.12
 4 A             4      0.908        1.93
 5 A             5      0.202        2.03
 6 B             1      0.898        0.857
 7 B             2      0.945        1.72
 8 B             3      0.661        2.27
 9 B             4      0.629        2.77
10 B             5      0.0618       2.70
```

Comment: Thank you @CPak . Minor correction to function, as I did not state that the new deposit should not decay the first year:

`custom <- function(z, decay) { ans <- accumulate(z, function(x, y) { ((x) * (1-decay)) + y }, .init=0); tail(ans, -1) }`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you try something like this? I like to break out the steps so it's easier to see what's happening. If I didn't understand it fully, leave a comment and I'll update my answer. You can also use this example dataframe in your question and show us the output you would like to see so we can follow along.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  tibble(
    treatment = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 5),
    years = rep(0:4, each = 2),
    new_deposit = rep(1:5*10, each = 2)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(treatment, years, new_deposit)


df %>%
  arrange(treatment, years) %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  mutate(
    prev_deposit = lag(new_deposit, default = 0),  
    running_sum = cumsum(prev_deposit),
    accumulated = running_sum * (1-0.046)^(years)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

#  treatment years new_deposit prev_deposit running_sum accumulated
#  <chr>     <int>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#  A             0          10            0           0        0   
#  A             1          20           10          10        9.54
#  A             2          30           20          30       27.3 
#  A             3          40           30          60       52.1 
#  A             4          50           40         100       82.8
```

Comment: nearly there - but this becomes wrong. This will apply (1-0.046)^(years) to the totalt sum, whereas what we need is TotalaccumYearX = (dep.A x (1-0.046)^(YearX-YearA) + dep.B x(1-0.046)^(YearX-YearB) + ..... + (dep.X). x (1).

Comment: I see another solution marked as answered. Let me know if you want me to tackle this further.